# jQuery DataTables rowReorder issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables along with the rowReorder plugin against a static table (non AJAX) - everything initialises fine but when I drag a row, whilst it moves within the table, when I drop it goes back to its original location without refreshing (i.e. it never actually moves location - am aware I will need to update via AJAX to get the move permanent but I need this to work first!)

I added this code to try and tell me what was happening:

```
    table.on('row-reorder', function (e, diff, edit) {
        var result = 'Reorder started on row: '+edit.triggerRow.data()[1]+'<br>';

        for (var i=0, ien=diff.length ; i<ien ; i++) {
            var rowData = table.row( diff[i].node ).data();

            result += rowData[1]+' updated to be in position '+
                diff[i].newData+' (was '+diff[i].oldData+')<br>';
        }

        $('#event-result').html('Event result:<br>'+result);
    });
```

and when I use this, in event-result, I get something like:

```
Event result:
Reorder started on row: 3
4 updated to be in position (was )
5 updated to be in position (was )
3 updated to be in position (was )
```

The plugin can see that I am trying to move row 3 but it doesn't seem to be able to determine where I am trying to drop it hence the new and old position are blank whereas on https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/events.html you can see that it should "know" the location to drop and where to re order the 2 adjoining columns to.

In all the examples I have seen there are no id's added to the rows etc so I assuming this is being caused by a plugin clashing - anyone seen this before and know how to fix?

Here is my whole Datatables code:

```
    $.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
        autoWidth: false,
        dom: '<"datatable-header"fBl><"datatable-scroll-wrap"t><"datatable-footer"ip>',
        language: {
            search: '<span></span> _INPUT_',
            lengthMenu: '<span></span> _MENU_',
            paginate: { 'first': 'First', 'last': 'Last', 'next': '&rarr;', 'previous': '&larr;' }
        }
    });                     
   // Column selectors
    var table = $('.datatable-button-html5-columns').DataTable({
        //dom: 'lBfrtip',
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns('.select-filter').every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        },
        colReorder: true,
        orderCellsTop: true,
        stateSave: true,
        pageLength: 10,
        order:[[ 1, "asc" ]],
        language: {
            url: "/assets/js/plugins/tables/datatables/lang/en.php"
        },          
        select: true,
        rowReorder: {
            selector: 'tr',
            update: true
        },          
        buttons: {            
            dom: {
                button: {
                    className: 'btn btn-default'
                }
            },
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'colvis',
                    titleAttr: 'Columns'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'copyHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
                {
                    text:      '<span id="resetTable">Reset</span>'
                }                   

            ]
        },
        responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column',
                target: 'tr'
            }
        },
        columnDefs: [
            {
                className: 'control',
                orderable: true,
                targets:   0
            }
        ]                           
    });

            // Setup event
    table.on('row-reorder', function (e, diff, edit) {
        var result = 'Reorder started on row: '+edit.triggerRow.data()[1]+'<br>';

        for (var i=0, ien=diff.length ; i<ien ; i++) {
            var rowData = table.row( diff[i].node ).data();

            result += rowData[1]+' updated to be in position '+
                diff[i].newData+' (was '+diff[i].oldData+')<br>';
        }

        $('#event-result').html('Event result:<br>'+result);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

In datatable initialization code, remove  order attribute. If we use order then drag and drop will not work.

[Example with order](https://jsfiddle.net/npramesh/0hwhddaj/1/) - not working

```
table = $('#ConfigMenuTable').DataTable({
  data: testData,
  "rowReorder":  {
                selector: 'td:nth-child(1)'
            },            
  "order":[[ 1, "asc" ]],
  "columns": [
                {"visible": false},                         
                {"width": "20%", "className": 'reorder'},                       
                {"visible": false,"searchable": true, "width": "15%"},     
                {"orderable": false, "searchable": false},  
                {"orderable": false, "searchable": false},
                {"orderable": true, "searchable": false}                
            ]

});
```

[Example without order](https://jsfiddle.net/npramesh/0hqmfxc4/1/) - working

```
table = $('#ConfigMenuTable').DataTable({
  data: testData,
  "rowReorder":  {
                selector: 'td:nth-child(1)'
            }, 
  "columns": [
                {"visible": false},     
                {"width": "20%", "className": 'reorder'},   
                {"visible": false,"searchable": true, "width": "15%"},  
                {"orderable": false, "searchable": false},
                {"orderable": false, "searchable": false},
                {"orderable": true, "searchable": false}                
            ]    
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding an ID or sequence to the table.  In the [basic initialization example](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/simple.html), it says:

> The first column in the table is a sequence number that provides the basis for the ordering.

In [that example](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/selector.html) it has a hidden sequence column:

```
columnDefs: [
    { targets: 0, visible: false }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

**this is code to destroy and reset datatable**

```
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#categoryListDataTable"))
{
    $("#categoryListDataTable").dataTable().fnDestroy();
}

var table = $('#categoryListDataTable').DataTable( {
    rowReorder: true,
} );


table.on( 'row-reorder', function ( e, diff, edit ) {
    var res = '';
    for ( var i=0, ien=diff.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
        res += diff[i].newData+'=';
    }
    res = res.substring(0, res.length - 1);
    getVal(res);
} );
```

**made this another function due to getting values and run ajax to save at server side**

```
function getVal(res)
{
    var atmp = res.split('=');
    var newId = '';
    var newArr = [];
    for(var i=0,j=atmp.length;i<j;i++)
    {
        newId = $('#categoryListDataTable').find("tr:eq("+atmp[i]+") input[type='hidden']").val();
        if(newId != '')
            newArr[atmp[i]] = newId;
    }

    var urlStr = '<?php echo base_url('admin/managecategories/reorderCategories');?>';
    $.ajax({
        data:{new_:newArr},
        url:urlStr,
        cache:false,
        method:'POST',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hope this will help you in problem

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Could you add a bit more description to this answer? The best answers normally have text that describes what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is getting a bit aged, but I had to work through it and thought I'd share what I did. My requirements had this a table with sortable rows, but ordering by header click was not a requirement and made the UI a bit confusing.

The HTML is a fairly standard table.

HTML

```
<table class="table table-responsive-md table-striped" id="maskEditTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Valid Characters</th>
        <th>Is&nbsp;Literal&nbsp;Character</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="123" /></td>
        <td>
            <label aria-label="Is Character Literal" for="needsAUniqueId"></label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="needsAUniqueId" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="456" /></td>
        <td>
            <label aria-label="Is Character Literal" for="needsAUniqueId"></label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="needsAUniqueId" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="789" /></td>
        <td>
            <label aria-label="Is Character Literal" for="needsAUniqueId"></label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="needsAUniqueId" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="abc" /></td>
        <td>
            <label aria-label="Is Character Literal" for="needsAUniqueId"></label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="needsAUniqueId" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="def" /></td>
        <td>
            <label aria-label="Is Character Literal" for="needsAUniqueId"></label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="needsAUniqueId" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The javascript is also fairly straight forward. The major difference is the addition of a draw event handler. This iterates the header fields and strips the class tag, and also removes the click handler. This code was called from a page onload hander.

JAVASCRIPT

```
function removeSorting() {
    $.each($('#maskEditTable').find('thead > tr > th'), function (i, header) {
        $(header).attr('class', null);
        $(header).off('click');
    });
}
function() init(){
    var tab = $('#maskEditTable')
        .DataTable({
        paging: false,
        info: false,
        searching: false,
        rowReorder: {
            selector: 'tr',
            update: true
        },
        order: [[0, "asc"]],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 0,
                visible: true
            }
        ]
        });
    tab.on('draw.dt', removeSorting);
    removeSorting();
}
```

The results are exactly what I was expecting and there is no visible effects on the redraw in any of my tests.

GL!