# Why the rowReorder datatable is not working?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am trying to use re-order for specific column in datatable but the row is not change after dragging complete. the row is back as it old position.

I use this library: [My Reference](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/restrictedOrdering.html)

Only column (red color) that able to change after dragging.

[image]

What I have tried as below:

```
<table id="routeTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive compact" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sorting</th>
            <th>Route Rank</th>
            <th>Pseudowire</th>
            <th>Tunnel</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

var table2 = $('#routeTable').DataTable({
    rowReorder: true,
    select: true,
    processing: false,
    destroy: true,
    ajax: { 
        url: api_url,
        crossDomain : true,
        type : "POST",
        cache : false,
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataSrc : function(a){...},
        data: function(d) {return JSON.stringify({...});}
    },
    columns: [
        { data : "rank",
            render: function(data){...}
        },
        { data : "rank",
            render: function(data){...}
        },
        { data : "rank",  // Only this column can be change after dragging
            render: function(data){...}
        },
        { data : "tunnel",
            render: function(data){...}
        }
    ],

    // I have try this but not working
    rowReorder: {
        selector: 'tr',
        update: true
    }

    // I have try this but not working
    rcolumnDefs: [
        { orderable: true, className: 'reorder', targets: 2 },
        { orderable: false, targets: '_all' }
    ]
});
```

Comment: make a jsfiddle

Comment: Maybe you can fix `rcolumnDefs` to `columnDefs`

Comment: This answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/44820554/1332837